# GeoNodes - Convex Hull Triangulation Issue

Tags: geometry-nodes

I’m having some issues with the convex hull node on my wrap generator.

The wrap generator basically uses a difference Boolean between a plane and the object (a hand in this case) you want to wrap around, deletes everything that is NOT intersecting edges, convert to a convex hull, then converting to a curve to get the boarder edge to deform geo around.

[image]

The problem is I am finding that the convex hull node is very unpredictable with triangulation. If you intersect a flat plane with an object, it produces a nice clean Ngon which makes extracting the border edges very simple. However if you introduce any rotations to the plane, the convex hull is very heavily triangulated and not useable.

[image]

So far my workaround was to extrude the convex hull to give it thickness and then Boolean the original plane with the extruded convex hull to get the intersecting edges but it does not produce predictable results a lot of the time as the extrusion is all over the place due to the messy convex hull topology.

Does anyone have a workaround to getting past this, is there a way to perhaps force the convex hull to always produce an Ngon to avoid the triangulation?

Thanks!

Comment: "normally" geometry node questions are answered very fast (and i tend to prefer the ones with blend files, so i don't have to waste my time recreating everything manually).

Comment: It's hard to help without an example .blend file in this case, I would try taking the convex hull, merge by distance (so it's flat and single-sided), then remove edges that have 2 neighbors (internal edges). Then convert to curve.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I ended up finding a solution on the blenderartists forum from the user Zebr4he4d. 

Thread here:
https://blenderartists.org/t/geonodes-convex-hull-triangulation-issue/1509445/2